# Fixing custom query for wordpress/elementor with Advanced Custom Fields relationship field post types

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I was wondering if someone could help me out.
I can't seem to get this case working (since I am a noob in PHP).

Case:
My wordpress site has **two 'post types'**:

- Webinar
- Spreker (speaker in dutch)

Via Advanced Custom Posts i've set up a relationship field in the webinar post type. So I can pick the speakers related to that particular post.

I use elementor and need to use the elementor's post widget to display the related speaker(s) via the single webinar page template. This has to be done by a custom query. In elementor you can set a custom query ID. This calls for a php query code.

Now I can't seem to get this query array code right.

Elementor documentation about custom queries:
https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/#Using_the_Custom_Filter

Some related answers on internet (but can't still seem to get it working):
[Custom Query Filter for Elementor Posts by relationship field (ACF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923768/custom-query-filter-for-elementor-posts-by-relationship-field-acf)

**The custom query ID i use in Elementor is 'Spreker_filter'**

My code:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/spreker_filter', function( $query ) {
// Get current meta Query
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
if ( ! $meta_query ) {
$meta_query = [];
}

// Append our meta query
$meta_query[] = [
'key' => 'sprekers',
'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
'compare' => 'in',
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like i was having the same problem.
I've resolved it with this custom query

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/retrieveLinkedCpts', function( $query ) {
    $ids = get_field( 'my_relationship_field', false, false );
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );
});
```

source : https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4916

Let me know if it works